# The value of a determinant of a k by k matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I would like to calculate the value of this determinant :
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 2^n & n2^{n-1} \\ 
0 & 0 & \dots & \dbinom n  0  & \dbinom n 1  & \dbinom n 2  \\
\vdots \\
\dbinom n 0 & \dbinom n 1  & \dots & \dbinom n {k-3}  & \dbinom n {k-2} & \dbinom n {k-1} \\
\dbinom n 1  & \dbinom n 2  & \dots & \dbinom n {k-2}  & \dbinom n {k-1}  & \dbinom n {k} 
\end{vmatrix}
$$
So, I multiplied the j-th column by $(-1)^j\dbinom {n+k-j-1}{k-j}$ for $j=1;2;...;k$ and I replaced the last column by their sum, then I used the formula $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{s}(-1)^j\dbinom n j \dbinom {n+s-j-1}{s-j}=0,$
The determinant becomes
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 2^n & n2^{n-1} \\ 
0 & 0 & \dots & \dbinom n  0  & \dbinom n 1  & 0  \\
\vdots \\
\dbinom n 0 & \dbinom n 1  & \dots & \dbinom n {k-3}  & \dbinom n {k-2} & 0 \\
\dbinom n 1  & \dbinom n 2  & \dots & \dbinom n {k-2}  & \dbinom n {k-1}  & -\dbinom  {n+k-1} k
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Could someone please continue from here.

Comment: Hint:  You need only consider the two terms from the two non-zero entries in the first row.

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, the correct latex command is \vdots not \hdots.

Comment: You can make use of a property of the binomial coefficients to simplify your calculations

Comment: @StannisBa what property ?

Comment: What is ${0 \choose n}$?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor $\dbinom 0 n =1$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the generalization.  But then, is ${1 \choose n}$ also $1$?  What about any ${n \choose k}$ when $ k > n$?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I edited the question